# Wordpress and WHMCS Integration - Global Variable Woes

Tags: wordpress, whmcs

After searching the internet for the past couple of days I've had no joy. I am attempting to integrate `WordPress` (lets say for now just the header and footer) with `WHMCS`.

I have taken the approach here to include `wp-blog-header.php` (I have also tried `wp-load.php`) in the `header.tpl` file within the default template in `WHMCS`.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

It's clear WordPress is being called, however I receive endless errors such as:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function main() on a non-object in /home/test/public_html/dev/wp-includes/functions.php on line 775
```

(This is the first error received when navigating to the `WHMCS` client area.)

From what I can tell the problem in a bit more detail seems to be the same as this post regarding global variables not working / being initialised inside functions as they should.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/integrating-wordpress-into-my-site-global-blues-and-many-non-objects

There are alternative methods of integrated, e.g. using html/css, but I want to include WordPress specifically to make use of its other features / widgets etc.

A further option is to use one of the WHMCS WordPress Bridges, but I specifically want to avoid using a 3rd party script to include WHMCS within WordPress for various reasons including security vulnerabilities and update dependencies.

I appreciate this is quite a niche question, but any advice in general as to why the global variables are not working? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested the PHP file acting alone? i.e.: `<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); require('./wp-load.php'); echo site_url(); ?>`, then `http://example.com/my-wp-connect.php`

Comment: Yes I have and it works perfectly. It therefore seems to me to be a conflict with the WHMCS framework somewhere

Comment: I need to see the code of functions.php around line 775 where the error occurred.